# How are targets formed for axon growth cones (CNS)?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, central-nervous-system

Axons have growth cones which find a route to their target using multiple methods (guidepost cells, attraction to target, etc...). My question is, what is the process that actually forms the target? For some given Axon A1 of Neuron A, why does it skip Neuron B, and go straight for Neuron C? How is a target formed on neuron C for Neuron A to connect to? Are there are any articles/readings on this topic? There is also the process of following the path of a pioneering axon. Does following a path of a pioneering axon take precedence over other forms of signaling? Does distance play a factor in choosing a target (Eg: Axon growth cone prefers closer target rather than distant target?)